# How to implement two steps who are similar

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Is there any way i can implement two stepts like this(see below) in a single function:

```
When I click on the "Button_name" button
When I click on the "Link_name" name
```

Is there any syntax so the cucumber won't care what will come after the string and on these two steps i will not need to make two different functions?

Usually i will implement them separately with something like this:

@When("^I look at the \"([^\"]*)\" button$") 
public void smt (String smt){   }

Comment: @When("^I look at the \"([^\"]*)\"  \"([^\"]*)\"$") and ignore the second argument?

Comment: It was a suggested solution :)

Comment: I deleted the comment(sorry):i thought you said i didn't write the text button after the \"([^\"]*)\" , not that you told me a guide to solving it

Comment: No problem :) but hope it makes sense, so that you have a whitespace and a second regexp that capture any remainder

Comment: What is the implementation of each step? If you need code specific to a "name" or "button" then you gain nothing by reusing a step definition.

Comment: @cYrixmorten  it only works if i put the element , in this case "button" as a string in the step When I look at the "button_name" "button" , but i don;t really want to do something like this

Comment: @Greg Burghardt for example i  take the button_name and i searched it with a function in a class filled with tags to take the path (id or css or xpath) to that specific element. I could implement a function for every step , but i thought that a switch will look better

Comment: Can you please post the Java code to implement each step? Otherwise we cannot give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could implement one step with one method, and pass what was clicked as an argument to that method.
However, this will make your test code more complicated. So please consider whether you **should**. Having complicated logic in your test code, will make your tests harder to understand and maintain, thus defeating their purpose imho.

If you want to reuse common functionality, the recommendation is to write helper methods that you can call from your step definition.

For example:

```
@When ("I click on the {string} button")
public void clickButton(String button) {
  clickButton(button);
}

@When ("I click on the "Link_name" name")
public void clickLink(String link) {
  clickLink(link);
}
```

and implement clickButton() and clickLink() to click a button or link respectively. (I've used different clickButton() and clickLink() methods in this example, because iirc these would use different types of elements.)

If needed (or you really want to use a switch) you could use a switch statement to get use the right selector based on the button or link name.

Alternatively, you could implement page objects, add all the relevant selectors for the page object there and call the method on the relevant page object that click that particular link/button, delegating the logic to interact with the UI to the page objects and calling this logic from your step definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If are different context one click button and other click link, the best practices is to have two different steps.

One of the bad practices of using BDD is to think about reusing code within steps.

When you have a lot of logic inside a step, any modification can affect many tests.

Should be concerned about code reuse in page objects.